# How do I run NetBeans JUnit tests from the command line?

Tags: netbeans, junit, command-line, scripting, junit4

I am working on a Java application project in NetBeans. I have added JUnit tests, with the `@Test` annotation. The tests work fine when I run them from the ‘Run Tests’ menu item.

I want to run the same tests from a command-line script. I do not know how NetBeans does this. I want a single command for testing the whole project. How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you are using maven, then `mvn clean test`

Comment: How can i see if netbeans is using maven ? And if no, i suppose maven runs a junit command ?

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans uses Ant as a build tool, and its default Ant configuration contains a number of useful targets. You can list them with the command `ant -projecthelp` (executed in your project directory), which should output, amongst other things,

```
test                    Run unit tests.
test-single             Run single unit test.
test-single-method      Run single unit test.
```

So, simply executing `ant test` will run all your unit tests on the command line. This will run the tests, write the test results to the standard output, and finish up with a brief summary (including a `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` message if all the tests passed, or `BUILD FAILED` if not).

The `ant test` command will return an appropriate exit code (0 if all tests passed, 1 if any failed), which can be useful -- for example, if you want to add a pre-commit hook to your version control system to forbid commits with failing unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

You should build your project on the command-line with a build tool like Maven, Ant or Gradle and not rely on Netbeans for building it. Please search for this tools.

You should also consider to read a book about software development like [Head First Software Development](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/head-first-software/9780596527358/). They explain why and how to us a build tool (e.g. chapter 6 1/2 of Head First Software Development).